# How to create dynamic component in Angular 2 with Dart?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, dart

I want to dynamically switch which templateUrl to use for an Angular 2 / Dart component.

I've found out that the way to go would be to dynamically create a new component to place the templateUrl for. There are several examples on how to achieve this using Angular 2 ComponentResolver with TypeScript, [for example this one](http://blog.lacolaco.net/post/dynamic-component-creation-in-angular-2/), but I've been failing in translating them to Dart.

Basically what I fail to do is passing a new component from a function:

```js
createComponentFactory(ComponentResolver resolver,
        ComponentMetadata metadata) {
    final cmpClass = class DynamicComponent {};
    final decoratedCmp = Component(metadata)(cmpClass);
    return resolver.resolveComponent(decoratedCmp);
}
```

The problem with this and other similar approaches with Dart is that I cannot set `class DynamicComponent {};` to a variable or return it from a function without getting build errors like this:

```
[DirectiveProcessor]:
  Failed with 5 errors
Error 1: line 37, column 22 of lib/projects/project_component.dart and parts: Expected an identifier
    final cmpClass = class DynamicComponent {};
                     ^^^^^
Error 2: line 37, column 22 of lib/projects/project_component.dart and parts: Expected to find ';'
    final cmpClass = class DynamicComponent {};
                     ^^^^^
Error 3: line 37, column 22 of lib/projects/project_component.dart and parts: Expected a statement
    final cmpClass = class DynamicComponent {};
                     ^^^^^
Error 4: line 37, column 22 of lib/projects/project_component.dart and parts: Unexpected token 'class'
    final cmpClass = class DynamicComponent {};
                     ^^^^^
Error 5: line 37, column 28 of lib/projects/project_component.dart and parts: Expected to find ';'
    final cmpClass = class DynamicComponent {};
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Creating a new component like this is the common stumbling block for me when following any of the examples I've seen for creating a dynamic component. Has anyone figured out how can you achieve this with Dart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't declare classes inline in Dart.

This should do what you want

```
class DynamicComponent {}

createComponentFactory(ComponentResolver resolver,
        ComponentMetadata metadata) {
    final cmpClass = DynamicComponent;
    final decoratedCmp = Component(metadata)(cmpClass);
    return resolver.resolveComponent(decoratedCmp);
}
```

Would be nice to see the full solution if you can make it work.

Comment: Many thanks! This solves the problem I had with the class declaration. I'm still working on the whole solution and once I have something that works properly I'll post the final version here.